# creating war using Maven and deploying on jboss

Tags: maven, servlets, jboss

I have created a maven project with basic archetype. created a web.xml under /webapp/WEB-INF .

web.xml is given as follows

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
          <welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>  

  </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

pom.xml is as shown below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tvashtra</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->


  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

home.html is present in webapp folder but outside WEB-INF directory.
along with this created a servlet by extending HttpServlet class like below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Login")
public class ServletOne extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException
    {
        try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Mukesh Khanna</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h2>My name is Ashish Parab</h2>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I ensure that jboss http port is working on 9080 port 
[image: jboss http port working]

now after doing all this, i deployed the war however nothing seems to work.

*

> http://localhost:9080/HelloWorld

*
*

> http://localhost:9080/HelloWorld/Login
>   *
>   both above links displaying message as "the site can't be reached"

context root is HelloWorld
[image: Web Project Setting]

upon googling/youtubing, i have come across many examples where they are using Tomcat server as plugin but i don't want that.

Thanks in advance

---

as suggested in below comment, i created jboss-web.xml and kept under WEB-INF
i am using JBOSS 7 EAP and below is the content of jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/HelloWorld</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

however still not able to hit the target http://localhost:9080/HelloWorld

Comment: What is your war file name ? You have to use jboss-web.xml to set the context root. Is this file present in your war ?

Comment: @ehsavoie war file is named after context root i.e. HelloWorld.war and jboss-web.xml was not used in project but later i made the recommended modification. please refer to edited thread of question post.

Comment: @ehsavoie i would appreciate if you have a look at jboss-web.xml as i doubt if it's version appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seems to be problem of multiple jboss instances running on a same machine.

followed the exact same procedure without jboss-web.xml

also removed servlet dependency from pom and added below one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

it worked like a charm!